# Is a sequence of real numbers defined as $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ or as $f:S\to\mathbb{R}$ for $S\subset\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

In my textbook a sequence is defined as a function from $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ but on wikipedia the domain can be any subset of $\mathbb{N}$. What definition is mostly used?

Comment: I see the definition from your book most often

Comment: I think wikipedia also allows the domain to be any interval in $\mathbb Z$

Comment: Your title is uninformative. Please use more precise titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition presented in Wikipedia is usually used to describe sub-sequences. The more common definition is the one in your book.

Comment: So if you take the first one as the definition of a a sequence then $(1,2,3)$ is not a sequence but $(1,2,3, 0,0,0,....)$ is?

Comment: That's correct. It's also important to mention that even the term sub-sequence usually refers to functions who's domain is an infinite subset of N. I.E - the term sequence (and sub sequence) almost always refers to an infinite list, no matter what definition you choose. (But that's just semantics an conventions)